# What happens if app is killed when using CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

Imagine you are using `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation` to fetch down any changes.

You have successfully fetched all changed `CKRecords`, however, you have not yet made a local cache at the moment. But you do have cached a new change token in `recordZoneChangeTokensUpdatedBlock`
You are about to make a local cache for the `CKRecords`, but somehow your user decided to kill your app, and you are terminated.

After a re-launch, you want to re-download changes, but now have the NEW change token, from the New Token forth, there were no changes made.

How to solve this?

---

Someone pointed out that I could cache the token after Records are written to the local database.

But that is not always possible, because, on initial launch of the app, the app may have to download lots of `CKRecords` which consumes memory if you don't process them in time, on the other hand, the `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation` uses TWO different blocks, one for new records fetched from server, another for token update. So you will have to write complex code to coordinate the TWO BLOCKS.

```
var recordChangedBlock
var recordZoneChangeTokensUpdatedBlock
```

Comment: I want a standard solution, that is, not some hack.

Comment: @TomHarrington any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Just don’t cache your change token until *after* you have updated your local record cache. Works for me...

EDII TO ADD:

Getting CloudKit syncing is a complex beast - at least to me it was! I'm new to iOS and it took me a LONG time to get my system working - with detours through learning about operation and GCD.  You're going to need to split it out into different operations or methods to complete successfully. Like you've said the sync can be interrupted/cancelled at any time and your system needs to be resilient to that.

I would recommend NOT using the CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation to process anything, just used to get those results and tokens, and then pass those on to the next step in your system.  I'm using operations, and I have a wrapper operation for the CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation  - it's one step in the chain for fetching, modifying and uploading changes.  This isn't the whole class, just the relevant snippets that apply to this question to give you an idea of what I mean.  Your code will be (probably very) different:

```
class FetchRecordZoneChangesOperation: AsyncOperation {

// MARK: - Properties

var inputRecordZoneIDs: [CKRecordZoneID]?

var outputCKRecords: [CKRecord]?
var outputDeletedRecordIDs: [CKRecordID]?
var outputServerChangeToken:  CKServerChangeToken?

var useServerChangeToken = true

override func main() {

    if self.isCancelled {
        self.finish()
        return
    }

    if let recordZoneIDsDependency = dependencies
        .filter({ $0 is CKRecordZoneIDsProvider })
        .first as? CKRecordZoneIDsProvider
        , inputRecordZoneIDs == nil {
        inputRecordZoneIDs = recordZoneIDsDependency.ckRecordZoneIDs
    }

    //  This record zone stuff is kinda redundant but it works...
    var recordZoneID: CKRecordZoneID
    var recordZoneIDs: [CKRecordZoneID]

    if let zoneIDs = self.inputRecordZoneIDs, let zoneID = zoneIDs.first {

        recordZoneID = zoneID
        recordZoneIDs = zoneIDs

    } else {

        recordZoneID = UserDefaults.standard.ckCurrentRecordZoneID
        recordZoneIDs = [UserDefaults.standard.ckCurrentRecordZoneID]

    }

let operation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation()
    // QOS

    operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated

    operation.recordZoneIDs = recordZoneIDs

    // if I have a database change token, use that, otherwise I'm getting all records

    if useServerChangeToken, let token = UserDefaults.standard.ckRecordZoneChangeToken {

        // TODO: This will change when I have more than 1 list

        let fetchOptions = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions()
        fetchOptions.previousServerChangeToken = token
        operation.optionsByRecordZoneID = [ recordZoneID : fetchOptions]
    }

    operation.recordChangedBlock = { record in
        if self.outputCKRecords != nil {
            self.outputCKRecords?.append(record)
        } else {
            self.outputCKRecords = [record]
        }
    }

    operation.recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock = { recordID, somethingStringy in
        if self.outputDeletedRecordIDs != nil {
            self.outputDeletedRecordIDs?.append(recordID)
        } else {
            self.outputDeletedRecordIDs = [recordID]
        }
    }

    operation.recordZoneChangeTokensUpdatedBlock = { recordZoneID, serverChangeToken, clientChangeTokenData in
        self.outputServerChangeToken = serverChangeToken
    }

    operation.recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock = { recordZoneID, serverChangeToken, clientChangeTokenData, moreComing, error in

    if error != nil {


                cloudKit.errorController.handle(error: error, operation: .fetchChanges)


        } else {

            // Do I need to handle things with the clientChangeTokenData? Working flawlessly without currently. Right now I just store the server one

            self.outputServerChangeToken = serverChangeToken

        }
    }
}
```

And then the next operation picks it up to modify the records locally:

```
class ModifyObjectsOperation: AsyncOperation {

var debug = true
var debugMore = false

var inputCKRecords: [CKRecord]?
var inputDeleteIDs: [CKRecordID]?

var inputRecordZoneChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken?
var inputDatabaseChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken?

override func main() {

    if isCancelled {
        self.finish()

        return
    }

    if let recordDependency = dependencies
        .filter({ $0 is CKRecordsProvider })
        .first as? CKRecordsProvider
        , inputCKRecords == nil {
        inputCKRecords = recordDependency.ckRecords
    }

    if let recordZoneTokenDependency = dependencies
        .filter({ $0 is CKRecordZoneTokenProvider })
        .first as? CKRecordZoneTokenProvider
        , inputRecordZoneChangeToken == nil {
        inputRecordZoneChangeToken = recordZoneTokenDependency.ckRecordZoneChangeToken
    }

    if let databaseTokenDependency = dependencies
        .filter({ $0 is CKDatabaseTokenProvider })
        .first as? CKDatabaseTokenProvider
        , inputDatabaseChangeToken == nil {
        inputDatabaseChangeToken = databaseTokenDependency.ckDatabaseChangeToken
    }

    if let deleteDependency = dependencies
        .filter({ $0 is CKRecordIDsProvider })
        .first as? CKRecordIDsProvider
        , inputDeleteIDs == nil {
        inputDeleteIDs = deleteDependency.ckRecordIDs
    }

    if self.inputCKRecords == nil && self.inputDeleteIDs == nil {
        if self.debug {
            print(" ModifyObjectsOperation - no changes or deletes ")
        }

        self.finish()
        return
    }

    // NOW MODIFY YOUR RECORDS HERE.  IF SUCCESSFUL, CACHE YOUR TOKEN.

}
```

If you've got a lot of data to sync or a large amount of records you're right that it will take multiple trips. Uploading is more painful than downloading... There's a 200 record upload limit (though I've found that's not too strictly enforced - I've uploaded up to 400 small records successfully at a time).  I've found I can get many thousands of small records downloaded in one block.

The only way to truly know that you're safe is to wait until you have the changes, cache your changes locally, and only then save that changeToken.  You'd much rather get duplicate data than lose something in the process.  And if you're doing it right there's never a time you could lose something, you just might end up doing a bit of redundant work.

EDIT 2:

Just saw the last part of your question above.  If your app is dependent on remote data to even be usable, it seems like you've only got a couple options.  Give some kind of progress indicator that they have to wait for before using the app. Or rearchitecting what you've got so that you can use the app BEFORE you have that remote data. It might not be in a final state but at least it will be usable.

For what I'm working on there could potentially be tens or hundreds of thousands of records on an initial sync and it would be unworkable to wait for those all to sync before using the app.  They can start using the app and the syncing can happen AS they're using and changing the underlying data because it's been built to be resilient to that.

Comment: Oops meant that as a comment, not an answer

Comment: Comment or answer, I believe you are correct, sir ;-)

Comment: @BrianM   But that is not possible to do. New records are returned from a different block other than the block to receive updated token. You have to write lots of complex code coordinate them

Comment: @BrianM  when the app is installed on a new device, the app has to download lots of CKRecords, which will consume lots of RAM if you don't process in a timely manner. I can't wait until all CKRecords are downloaded and then write them to local database.

Comment: @BrianM  You can try write some code and paste it here. I really don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Popmedic Hi, thanks for your answer, pls check the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Use Long Lived Operations. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckoperation

```
        zoneOperation.configuration.isLongLived = true
```